# If current_time then do this else do this

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have an expressionengine site and I want to create a news template that populates with only one year of stories. The following code does work and populate the page with the correct year of stories.

```
<?$date = strtotime('{current_time format="%Y"} -1 year');?>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" start_on="<?echo date('Y', $date);?>-12-31 20:00" dynamic="no"}
```

BUT in January and Feburary I would not have many posts on the page so I want to something like:

```
{if '{current_time format="%M"} = "Jan"'}
<?$date = strtotime('{current_time format="%Y"} -2 year');?>
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" start_on="<?echo date('Y', $date);?>-12-31 20:00" dynamic="no"}
{if:else}
<?$date = strtotime('{current_time format="%Y"} -1 year');?>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" start_on="<?echo date('Y', $date);?>-12-31 20:00" dynamic="no"}
{/if}
```

I can't seem to figure out the PHP for the IF current time = Jan

Comment: I'm not familiar with expressionengine, but I'm pretty sure that %Y will never be a month's name

Comment: In ExpressionEngine you can show current date by the following code:

`{current_time format="%F %d %Y"}`

It would render as January 8 2015

Comment: then you should try to change ... "&Y"} = "Jan" to ..."%F" == "January"...

Comment: Michael I meant for it to be "%M". I tried "%F" and it just outputs the full month name instead of short form. Looking up the variables the month can be ("%m" = 01; "%M = Jan; and "%F = January).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation found here https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html

You should use

```
{if {current_time format="%M"} == "Jan"}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The statement is always "True" even if I change the month. I simpilfied my code to make sure something else wasn't causing the issue and had the same result. Here is the code:

`{if '{current_time format="%M"} == "Jan"'}
<p>Month is January</p>
{if:else}
<p>Month is not January</p>
{/if}`

If I change "Jan" to "Feb" the code still outputs "Month is January"

Comment: I think the logic is correct, the syntax may be wrong, but like I said I am not familiar with expressionengine. It seems you don't need the quotes. Code edited.

Comment: PERFECT! That worked. I thought I tried that version before, but I guess not. Thank you!